# unused variable React preventing react element from printing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Whenever I do an npm run watch, I get this warning:

```
WARNING in react-profile-page.1.0.0.min.js from UglifyJs
Side effects in initialization of unused variable React [./js/index.js:3,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ReactDOM [./js/index.js:4,4]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:136,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js:97,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:982,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:265,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:285,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:91,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js:36,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable Transaction [./~/react/lib/ReactServerUpdateQueue.js:18,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:54,0]
Condition always true [./~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:56,0]
```

Everywhere I read online seems to tell me these warnings should be disregarded, hwoever whenever I try to run my HTML page on my browser:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>First React Page</title>
  <!--remember to change the name of your build files and match them here-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="react-profile-page.1.0.0.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="app"></div>

</body>

<script src="react-profile-page.1.0.0.js"></script>
</html>
```

I just get a blank screen, meaning that the react elements i've made in my index.js arent being read. So this warning must be why, right?

Here's index.js:

```
"use strict"
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


var Person = function() {
    var name = 'Derek Zoolander';
    var imageUrl = 'http://uifaces.com/assets/static/images/zoolander.jpg';
    var job = 'Male model';
    return (
        <div className="person">
            <div className="person-name">{name}</div>
            <img className="person-img" src={imageUrl} />
            <div className="person-job">
                {job}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

I just get a blank screen, meaning that the react elements i've made in my index.js arent being read. So this warning must be why, right? I tried getting rid of "use strict" and that eliminated the first two warningsm, but still not loading in the browser.

Comment: It is rendering fine on my machine...does your console give any errors? Is the html 404'ing when loading your .js file?

Comment: Tried checking if your `DOMContentLoaded` function handler is actually firing? Have you considered adding the `<script ...>` tag to just before the closing `</body>`  tag (that way your js code doesn't have to wait for the DOM to be ready)?